# How to set link colors in a RichEditableText component

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex4

I've got some text that includes links that I display in a RichEditableText component. How do I change the color of the links from the default blue?  I tried the [example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/10/21/customizing-the-appearance-or-a-hyperlink-in-a-textflow-object-in-flex-4) posted by Peter deHaan but it doesn't work with SDK 4.1.  I found a way to [do this in MXML](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2530962#2530962), but the text needs to be localizable which means I load it at runtime based on the locale, so I can't just include it inline with the MXML.

To recap: How do I set the link colors for a RichEditableText component that displays HTML that gets loaded at runtime?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this globally, it was in another example on Peter deHaan's site:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/03/17/globally-styling-anchor-tags-on-a-textview-control-in-flex-gumbo/

It's unfortunate you can't set these sorts of things with CSS...

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a nested `span` tag to colorize your links as you prefer:

```
<s:RichEditableText id="titleText"
        width="100%"
        editable="false"
        selectable="false"
        focusEnabled="false">
    <s:textFlow>
        <s:TextFlow>
            <s:a click="titleText_clickHandler(event)">
                <s:span color="#FF0000">
                    Link's text here
                </s:span>
            </s:a>
        </s:TextFlow>
    </s:textFlow>
</s:RichEditableText>
```